# Possible to select 2nd column and add background color for odd row of 2nd column?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I would like to select 2nd tr and then select only odd td only with SCSS

I just do not want to add more javascript if it can be done by CSS.
I have tried

```
tr td:nth-child(2) {
  &::nth-child(odd) {
    backgroud: red;
  }


}

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the result I am expecting. But only with css selector not using class like red
https://jsfiddle.net/9g436bds/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this, depending on your needs, is to target both `tr` and `td` simultaneously

```
tr td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: grey;  
}

tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jdxwBE

Comment: Link has some issue I think it just load forever. And you are selecting 2 row not column. tr td:nth-child(2)  this is selecting second column. Added link shows expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Note: Your header and the text in your question ask for different things.

So, first I am answering the text inside the question ("select 2nd tr and then select only odd td"):

With or without SCSS, the selector for that would be `tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(odd)`:

```css
tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(odd) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>765</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>rtz</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>gfd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>678</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>bvc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here's an answer to the question in the header ("select 2nd column and add background for off td"). Very similar selector, but the pseudo classes turned around:

```css
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>765</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>rtz</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>gfd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>678</td>
    <td>123</td>
    <td>345</td>
    <td>bvc</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```